# Is there a possible way to update OpenGL ES from 3.0 to 3.1?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator

I need to use both **OpenGL ES 3.1** and Vulkan in BlueStacks 5 (Android Pie). But it doesn't work.

It's the report from AIDA64 in Bluestacks 5

> OpenGL ES version: 3.0
>
> GPU version: OpenGL ES 3.1 (4.5.0 NVIDIA 497.09)

It's available for my PC to use OpenGL ES 3.2. However, in the emulator, it seems unpossible.

I've tried other emulators, but only Nox and Bluestacks support Android 9 so far.

Eh... Nox doesn't support Vulkan. (Or is there a way to add Vulkan support for Nox?)

My hardware device

> CPU: AMD R7-5800H
>
> GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop

THANKS :)